# C code connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, c, linux

I have a c code in Linux Ubuntu system.

I used this command to install the library

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then I used a test code to check the installing.

```
#include <mysql/my_global.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());

  exit(0);
}
```

When I built the code in Netbean by GCC, it shows the error message:

> In file included from mysql.c:1:0:
>   /usr/include/mysql/my_global.h:77:23: fatal error: my_config.h: No
>   such file or directory

I have check the include file. They are exist.

Comment: Did you check that the file exists? Linux is not enough information, is it Ubuntu, Debian or any derivative?

Comment: Hi @iharob I have checked the file. It's exists. I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Just add `-I/usr/include/mysql` to the `CFLAGS` and remove `<mysql/` from the includes.

Comment: @iharob I added **-I/usr/include/mysql** to Netbean by **Build - C Complier - Addition Options**. It still said that can't find these two library after I remove the **mysql/**. I can find these library when I go into **usr/include/mysql** directly.

Comment: This is not a library it's a header. You should not include `my_globalh` directly, and don't use netbeans it's better suited for Java, try some build system I recommend cmake because it's easy to write CMakeLists.txt files.

Comment: @iharob Thank you for your suggestion. I will try cmake later. Do you have any idea about the issue of my code at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you haven't specified the correct include paths on your compilation command.

MySQL doesn't use `pkg-config`, but has a very similar `mysql_config` command:

```
$ mysql_config --cflags
-I/usr/include/mysql -DBIG_JOINS=1  -fno-strict-aliasing   -g -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing
```

Normally, you'd use it in your Makefile something like this:

```
CFLAGS += $(shell mysql_config --cflags)
CXXFLAGS += $(shell mysql_config --cxxflags)
LDLIBS += $(shell mysql_config --libs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that when I build the code as it follows, it works

```
$ mysql_config --libs
$ mysql_config --cflags
$ gcc -o output_file $(mysql_config --cflags) source_file.c $(mysql_config --libs)
$ ./output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this For GNU C compiler

```
  gcc source_file.c -o output_file -std=c99  `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
  ./output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE, please do these steps:

1. Add `/usr/include/mysql` to include path list (`-I` switch in GCC command-line).
2. Add `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to library search path list (`-L` switch in GCC command-line)
3. Link to `pthread` and `mysqlclient` libraries (`-l` switch in GCC command-line)

Also you should include MySqlClient library using:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
```